# Ruby Anagram Comparison Module

Tags: ruby

I am new to Ruby and trying to figure out a problem for an online test. The problem is as follows:

> An anagram is a word formed from another by rearranging its letters,
>   using all the original letters exactly once; for example, orchestra
>   can be rearranged into carthorse.
>
> Write a function that checks if two words are each other's anagrams.
>
> For example, AreAnagrams.are_anagrams?('momdad', 'dadmom') should
>   return true as arguments are anagrams.

The code I have come up with is this:

```
module AreAnagrams
  def self.are_anagrams?(string_a, string_b)
      ## Create @word1 variable to store string_a
      @word1 = string_a

      ## Create @word1_compare variable to store string_a in lower case
      @word1_compare = @word1.downcase

      ## Create @word2_compare variable to store string_b
      @word2 = string_b

      ## Create @word2_compare variable to store string_b in lower case
      @word2_compare = @word2.downcase

      ## Check length of @word1 and @word2 to make sure they are the same length
      if @word1.length == @word2.length

      =begin
        Sort the letters of the @word1 and @word2 variables and compare
        them to see if they are anagrams
      =end

      if @word1_compare.chars.sort.join == @word2_compare.chars.sort.join
          puts "#{@word1} and #{@word2} are anagrams!"
      else
          puts "#{@word1} and #{@word2} are not anagrams!"
      end
      else
          puts "#{@word1} and #{@word2} are not anagrams!"
      end
  end
end
```

When I submit the code, I get the following back from the test:

> Compilation OK, but 4 out of 4 test cases fail
>
> Sample case: Wrong answer
>
> Words with unique letters: Wrong answer
>
> Words with duplicate letters: Wrong answer
>
> One word is the prefix of another word: Wrong answer

I have tested my code with multiple strings and it seems to work just fine. It looks like it wants me to check for more specific instances (special characters, words with duplicate letters, etc.) but is that really required? Sorry if it's a dumb question, I'm new to Ruby and lost.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Since this is a class method, you should *really* avoid using instance variables in here. Those will persist between calls of the method, something you probably didn't intend. Just use regular local variables, no `@` required.

Comment: Sounds good, I will correct my variables as well. Much appreciated, thank you again!

Comment: @tadman has answered your question, but there are a few things you could do to improve your method. 1, The problem does not ask you to `puts`, so you should remove that. 2. When you want to return a result (e.g., `true` or `false`) and also `puts` the the result, it's generally best to `puts` outside the method. That makes the method more versatile, should you want to use it again, elsewhere in your program, with no or different `puts` messages...

Comment: ...3. You should use local variables rather instance variables (`word1` rather than `@word`, as instance variables are visible outside the method, which you don't want. That's not a problem here, but don't use instance variables unless you need them to be visible outside the current scope. 4. You don't need to check the length, unless you want to do that for reasons of efficiency. 5. You don't need `join`. 6. You don't need all those temporary variables. Just write `string_a.downcase.chars.sort == string_b.downcase.chars.sort`. That is, the method only requires that single line.

Comment: Thank you for the information Cary. I didn't know that using 'puts' is generally better outside of a method and I appreciate your help with this. I have since modified my code with your suggestions and not only is it considerably smaller it is 100% right. Thank you very much to both you and tadman!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem here is you're displaying a message but not returning a `true` or `false` value which is what is expected.

After each `puts`, include the appropriate answer. That way your method will return something useful. Right now I'm presuming it's `nil` for all cases, since that's what `puts` returns.

Comment: Now that you've identified the problem, perhaps a few words on how the code can be improved...

Comment: @CarySwoveland I thought that was pretty clear. All that needs to be done is adding `true` or `false` after each puts.

Comment: Use of temporary variables, use of instance variables, having `'puts` inside the method, etc.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Already remarked above on the question itself, so hopefully that helps. This is a solution that's 90% there, I'm just getting it over the hump. The rest is all about finesse.

Comment: Thanks tadman! All I had to do was replace the "puts" lines to "return true" or "return false" and voila.

Comment: Good news. Remember Ruby returns things implicitly, so often a `return` statement is not necessary unless there's a need to explicitly break out of your method early.